# Reverse Engineering - Precision and Recall

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I am trying to understand Precision and Recall

**Formula**

Precision = TP/(TP+FP) | Recall = TP/(TP+FN)

**The Story**

1. In an input image, there are `N` birds[Ground Truth],
2. Our model predicted/identified `M` birds in the input image
3. Precision and Recall is calculated based on TP, FP, FN

   We got Precision = 0.173 and Recall = 0.75

Let me correct, if this Reverse Engineering calculation is not correct

Let assume, N=50,

**1**: If Recall = 0.75, then recall means -> out of 50 birds, the model correctly predicted around 37 birds?
If yes, then the True Positive is approx. 37?

Calculation -

```
75% of 50 is around 37
If TP ~ 37.5, FN ~ 12, then Recall = 0.75
```

**2**: If Precision = 0.173, then precision means -> actually there are 50 birds in the input image, but the model predicted 216 birds in the image?

Calculation -

```
If TP ~ 37.5, FP ~ 179, then Precision = 0.173
```

Help me confirm this battle, thanks

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Yes, your calculations are correct.

Comment: @Erwan, thanks for confirming